# R - grep remove UPPER case rows

Tags: r, regex

I would like to remove all the rows containing UPPERCASE words.

My data looks like this :

```
                                      dt
1        TRAVEL AND UNSPECIFIED TIME USE
2                      TRAVEL BY PURPOSE
3 Travel related to unspecified time use
4    Travel related to personal business
```

I don't understand why this isn't working

```
dt[-c(grep('[A-Z]', dt$dt)) , ]
```

Because, strangely it works when I generate random data on `mtcars` like this :

```
l = sample( c(letters[1:16], LETTERS[1:16]) ) 
mtcars$code = l
mtcars[-c( grep('[A-Z]', mtcars$code) ) , ]
```

Can someone help me ?

```
dt = c("TRAVEL AND UNSPECIFIED TIME USE", 
"TRAVEL BY PURPOSE", 
"Travel related to unspecified time use",
"Travel related to personal business") 
dt = as.data.frame(dt)
dt$dt = as.character(dt$dt)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to capital letteres, there is also space, so we can match one or more capital letters including space (`[A-Z ]+`) from start (`^`) of string to end (`$`) in the `grepl`, and negate (`!`) to return elements that includes lower-case or lower-case with upper case (mixed) or all other possibilities.

```
dt[!grepl("^[A-Z ]+$",dt$dt),, drop = FALSE]
#                                   dt
#3 Travel related to unspecified time use
#4    Travel related to personal business
```

---

In the OP's other example 'l', there is only a single character per string.  So, using `[A-Z]` works, however, it is better not to use `-`.  For example, suppose we have a vector with all the elements in lower-case

```
v1 <- c('a', 'aB', 'b')
v1[-grep("^[A-Z]+$", v1)]
#character(0)
```

as

```
grep("^[A-Z]+$", v1)
#integer(0)
```

However, negating (`!`) will get the expected output

```
 v1[!grepl("^[A-Z]+$", v1)]
 #[1] "a"  "aB" "b"
```

Comment: @giacomoV  It is `grepl` and not `grep`.