# Removing rows that contain above a certain share of upper-case letters in R

Tags: r, string, nlp, grepl

I have a large dataframe that consists of company identifiers and extracted phrases from newspapers. It is very messy, and I want to clean it by conditional row removing.

[image]

For this I want to remove rows that have more then 50% upper-case letters.

I have found [this code from a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71135763/removing-rows-from-data-frame-containing-strictly-uppercase-letters-in-a-specif) which will remove me rows with all upper-case letters:

```
data <- data[!grepl("^[A-Z]+(?:[ -][A-Z]+)*$", data$text), ]
```

How can I express it as a share of the total word or letter count?

Comment: Please post data as text instead of a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with regular expressions, but the `stringi` function `stri_count_charclass` provide a highly optimized version for detecting categories of characters. The package manual documents the [List of Unicode General Categories](https://stringi.gagolewski.com/rapi/about_search_charclass.html#unicode-general-categories), here we use string `L` for all letters, and `Lu` for uppercase letters.

Something like this should accomplish what you need:

```
library(stringi)

data <- data.frame(text = c("Foo",
                            "BAr",
                            "BAZ"))

data[which(stri_count_charclass(data[["text"]],"[\\p{Lu}]") / stri_count_charclass(data[["text"]],"[\\p{L}]") < 0.5),]
# [1] "Foo"
```

*One note: I updated my answer here since I failed to point out a powerful feature of `stringi` in my original response.* My instinctive reaction was to use `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]` to signify lower and upper case characters, respectively. However, using Unicode general categories allows the solution to work well for non-ascii characters as well.

```
x = c("Foo",
      "BAr",
      "BAZ",
      "Ḟoo",
      "ḂÁr",
      "ḂÁẒ")
stri_count_charclass(x,"[A-Z]")/stri_count_charclass(x,"[[a-z][A-Z]]")
[1] 0.3333333 0.6666667 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000       NaN

stri_count_charclass(x,"[\\p{Lu}]")/stri_count_charclass(x,"[\\p{L}]")
[1] 0.3333333 0.6666667 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.6666667 1.0000000
```